# RSA Encryption of Python List

Tags: python, list, rsa

I am having troubling encrypting a Python list element by element. Each element is this list is a string. Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

#### Generate the public and private keys ####
key = RSA.generate(1024, e=65537)
priv_key = key.exportKey("PEM")
public_key = key.publickey().exportKey("PEM")


#Let's get some information!!
firstName = input("Enter your First Name: ") 
lastName = input("Enter your Last Name: ") 
id = input("Enter your Personal ID: ") 

#list = [first_name, last_name, id]
list = ['Bob', 'Dylan', '15898']
listEncrypted = []

#Now let's encrypt the list with a public key
list_length = len(list)

for index in range(list_length-1):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(list[index])
    listEncrypted.append(ciphertext)
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
  File "C:\Users\moo\.spyder-py3\RSA.py", line 122, in <module>
  ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(list[index])

  File "C:\Users\moo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 107, in encrypt
  modBits = Crypto.Util.number.size(self._key.n)

  AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'n'
```

How do I encrypt the list using the user's input? Please help...

Comment: What is `counter_public_key`?

Comment: The example you posted doesn't match the error - and it has other bugs. How about an updated example that is easier for us to run? We don't need input prompts and a list, just a single canned string encryption that fails the same way.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I changed the name. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @tdelaney I commented out the previous list and created a new one under it. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure this is your only bug but you shouldn't be exporting the key. You should just use the key object as output by `RSA.generate()` (ie, make it `PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)`)

Comment: @Unn Does PKCS1_OAEP.new(key) know to use the public key to make the ciphertext?

Comment: I assume those first few lines where you create the key are just for test. Normally, one program creates and saves the keys and others read and use them. You might want to note that in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptographic keys are usually generated once and saved to files in one of several formats. Its also common for the private key to be further protected with a password or stored in a secure place in your file system.

To encrypt with the public key you normally get the key from some external source, but for this test code we use the test key we generated.

I'm not sure about Crypto versions, but mine uses camelCase for method names, although lower_case is used in other examples.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

#### Generate the public and private keys for test ####
key = RSA.generate(1024, e=65537)
priv_key = key.exportKey("PEM")
public_key = key.publickey().exportKey("PEM")

text = "This is secret"

#Now let's encrypt the list with a public key
key = RSA.importKey(public_key)
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(text.encode("utf-8"))
print(text, ciphertext)
```